# HTML Problem in displaying the items in different lines

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show three copies of the image in each line dynamically when I read it from the database, but it shows all the images next to each other. I tried to edit the code so it copies it but didn't work

How to make show three images in each line regardless of the number of items in the database?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require "init.php";
    login();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Expert System </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' align='center'     >
<?php
// LOGIN USER
function login(){
    global $con;
    global $counter;

    //$email = $mysqli->escape_string('');
    $query="SELECT * FROM users ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "User with that ID doesn't exist!";
    else { // User exists
        $counter=0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>
                <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo '<td>
                    <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo '<td>
                <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: This message `echo "User with that ID doesn't exist!";` should read `echo "NO users exist in the database";`

Comment: @SalehRefaai You gave those image tags in only one `<tr>` that's why images are displaying besides each other. To achieve your goal you must give only one image  tag to the `<tr>` or just use the CSS property `td {
    display: block;
}`. It'll solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a long discussion with the owner of this question, I'm posting my solution.
In your code you have to just move the **table tag** inside function.

```
<?php
// LOGIN USER
function login(){
// write remaining code.... and then use this while loop
echo '<table border="1" align="center">';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {   echo '<tr>';
       // If you want 2 images in a row than use $i<= 2
       for($i= 1; $i<= 3; $i++)
       {
        echo '<td><img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" ></td>';   
       }
       echo '</tr>';
  } // while
} // login()
```

Comment: Welcome always :) !

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<tr> <img...> <tr>` and remove `<td>` tag. `<tr>` represents row and `<td>` represents column. So because your `<img>` is inside `<td>` tags in `<tr>`, it is appearing in one row.

Here echo will not work, first made complete HTML then echo it once at the end. let see the example below.

Let see below, first what I am observing is that you are adding the same image thrice while it looks like you want to append the next image in the next row not the same image in each row.

Below I am just changing your code to show images in separate rows

```
$imagetags = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $imagetags .=  "<tr><td>";
    $imagetags .=  '<img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >'
    $imagetags .=  "</td></tr>";
    $imagetags .=  "<tr><td>";
    $imagetags .=  '<img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >'
    $imagetags .=  "</td></tr>";
    $imagetags .=  "<tr><td>";
    $imagetags .=  '<img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >'
    $imagetags .=  "</td></tr>";
}
```

But to show next image from DB row, in next row on HTML, you have to made changes in your code like below

```
$imagetags = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $imagetags .=  "<tr><td>";
    $imagetags .=  '<img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >'
    $imagetags .=  "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: I have not enough score to comment. Sorry for this.

Comment: And `<tr>`'s need a `<td> .. </td>` inside them so thats not valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

that what shows with your code:
[image]

and that with my code:

[image]

Comment: this is the output @Alex

Comment: inspect element  table and print screen that, that code shouldn't output something like this

Comment: @SalehRefaai Try this `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $counter == 0)`

Comment: It appears that your images are outside `<table>` , that is why it is not showing properly

Answer (score 0):

You declared function inside of table but you called it before any html,that is why your images are not inside a table and not styled correctly, try this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require "init.php";
// LOGIN USER
function login(){
    global $con;
    global $counter;

    //$email = $mysqli->escape_string('');
    $query="SELECT * FROM users ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "User with that ID doesn't exist!";
    else { // User exists
        $counter=0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>
                <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo '<td>
                    <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo '<td>
                <img src="images/' . $row["category"]. '" width="250px"  height= "150px" alt="Avatar" >
                </td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);


?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Expert System </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' align='center'     >
 <?php login(); ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```